# Label View eventlistener not working in Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am creating Array of LabelView in my application during the run time and adding it to a TableView. But click EventListener not working for LabelView, Here is my sample code

```
var picRow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();
var photoContainer = Ti.UI.createView({
    top:0,
    width:300,
    left:15,
    right:5,
    height:200
})
picRow.add(photoContainer);  

var shareTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data:[picRow],
    top:10,
    left:0,
    right:0,
    height:250,
    separatorColor: '#ccc',
    backgroundColor:'transparent'
});
win.add(shareTable);

var pushleft = 5;
var pushtop = 5;
var images = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++){
    images[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel({
         backgroundImage: imageArray[i].image, // path to image at applicationDataDirectory
         width: 70  ,
         height: 70,
         "tickOption":false,
         "index":i,
         "picId":imageArray[i].picId,
         left: pushleft + 25, // logic for positioning
         top: pushtop + 5
    });
    pushleft = pushleft + 80;
    pushtop = pushtop + 50;
    photoContainer.add(images[i]);

    images[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
         alert(e);
    }); 
}
```

Here I am not getting any alert while clicking on the label view. Also I am not getting any error. Anyone help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance. I am using Titanium 1.7.5 and ios

Answer (score 0):

it is a best practice to put the eventlistener on the whole row and then look at the click event object to determine which object received the click.

so for example you would look for the picId of the object, if it existed, you would know that a label was clicked

Comment: Can you please provide code example for " look for the picId of the object, if it existed, you would know that a label was clicked " ???